# Delete $img_url in Adamant portfolio

Tags: wordpress, url

I'm implementing the portfolio page template, however I'd like to delete the URL's behind all portfolio images. (see page temp below)
Example website: http://demo.fabthemes.com/adament/my-portfolio/

Could anyone help me delete the URL? Once I delete the  $img_url part, my portfolio doesn't get displayed.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.

 Template name:Portfolio
 *
 * @package fabframe
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="full-wrap">
<ul class="folio-grid stylefx">
        <?php
        if ( get_query_var('paged') )
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        elseif ( get_query_var('page') )
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        else
            $paged = 1;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' =>-1));
        ?>

        <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

        <li>

          <figure>
                <?php
                    $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
                    $image = aq_resize( $img_url,720, 480, true ); //resize & crop the image
                ?>

                <?php if($image) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <figcaption>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <span><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'genre', '', ', ' ); ?></span>

            </figcaption>
        </figure>

         </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this:

```
<?php if($image) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To:

```
<?php if ( $image ) : ?>
    <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"/></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Why keep the anchor tags at all? From a user experience point of view, it would be even better to remove the anchor tags (<a...> and </a>) so that users are not tricked into clicking on images.  They will undoubtedly be tempted to do so when they see their cursors change when they hover over the images.

Comment: I agree but the anchor tags could be relevant in styling and my answer was to solve the immediate problem and not add more.